# Problems when uploading two times using same function php

Tags: php, unset

I'm having problems with a file upload script for my site. I've copied a simple upload script, and I'm setting it up so that I can upload multiple files. I have to do this by first making one form for one file, then a copy of the form for the next one and so one. (I first set the page up with the "multiple" tag in the form, but then i discovered that the IE at work is version 8, and no flash. So I have to do it this way)

The scripts uploads ok. The problem is that the second file is called file1.jpgfile2.jpg, the third one file1.jpgfile2.jpgfile3.jpg and so on.

this is my form, followed by the code with form #2 File #2 and on goes through the same form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="rediger.php?choice=addpicturetoproc">
              <input type="hidden" name="uploadpath" value="<? echo "Prosedyrer/$hovedkategori/$underkategori/$navn/$mappe_navn/" ?>">
              Bildefil: <input type="file" name="fileup" value=""><br>
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
              </form>
              <br>

              <?
}


elseif ($choice=="addpicturetoproc")
{

$max_size = 2000;          // maximum file size, in KiloBytes
$alwidth = 1900;            // maximum allowed width, in pixels
$alheight = 1800;           // maximum allowed height, in pixels
$allowtype = array('bmp', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpe', 'png');        // allowed extensions

if(isset($_FILES['fileup']) && strlen($_FILES['fileup']['name']) > 1) {
  $uploadpath = $uploadpath . basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name']);       // gets the file name
  $sepext = explode('.', strtolower($_FILES['fileup']['name']));
  $type = end($sepext);       // gets extension
  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name']);     // gets image width and height
  $err = '';         // to store the errors

  // Checks if the file has allowed type, size, width and height (for images)
  if(!in_array($type, $allowtype)) $err .= 'The file: <b>'. $_FILES['fileup']['name']. '</b> not has the allowed extension type.';
  if($_FILES['fileup']['size'] > $max_size*1000) $err .= '<br/>Maximum file size must be: '. $max_size. ' KB.';
  if(isset($width) && isset($height) && ($width >= $alwidth || $height >= $alheight)) $err .= '<br/>The maximum Width x Height must be: '. $alwidth. ' x '. $alheight;

  // If no errors, upload the image, else, output the errors
  if($err == '') {
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name'], $uploadpath)) { 
      echo '<h1>Filen: <b>'. basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name']). '</b> ble lastet opp!</h1>';

    }
    else echo '<b>Feil ved opplastning.</b>';
  }
  else echo $err;
}
    ?><p>Do you need another upload?</p>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="rediger.php?choice=addpicturetoproc">
              <input type="hidden" name="uploadpath" value="<? echo $uploadpath; ?>">
              Bildefil: <input type="file" name="fileup" value="Sett inn bildefilen her"><br>
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Last opp bildefil">
              </form>
              <br>
              <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="rediger.php?choice=menu">
               <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Nei, jeg er ferdig">
              </form>
```

I have tried using unset($fileup); before the second run, but still filename1.jpgfilename2.jpg.

Any obvious solutions?

Comment: Why is the `$uploadpath` var being used at the second form?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you're appending to the $uploadpath

```
$uploadpath = $uploadpath . basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name']);
```

So the first file will be `file1.jpg` then the second file will be `file1.jpgfile2.jpg` and so on.

I would suggest setting the base upload path to a different variable and trying something like

```
$uploadpath = $baseuploadpath . basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name']);
```